# Flex: BlazeDs deserialization

Tags: spring, apache-flex, serialization, deserialization, blazeds

I'm working on a webapp built using Spring + Flex. Communication between front and back uses BlazeDS and I have a custom marshaller in order to serialize data from flex to backend as:

```
<channel-definition id="my-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
        <endpoint url="http://localhost:8080/${context.root.cpanel}/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
        <properties>    
            <serialization>
                <type-marshaller>es.onebox.flex.messaging.io.CustomTypeMarshaller</type-marshaller>
            </serialization>
        </properties>
    </channel-definition>
```

Is there a way to configure how use a custom de-serializer from back to flex ? I need an interceptor to modify some fields of data sent from back to flex so I think this approach could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used an interceptor for Flex using:

```
<flex:message-interceptor ref="myMessageInterceptor"/>
```

And on my application.xml I've defined myMessageInterceptor as:

```
<bean id="myMessageInterceptor" class="es.onebox.flex.messaging.io.FlexInterceptor"/>
```

And this is de content of the interceptor:

```
public class FlexInterceptor implements ResourceHandlingMessageInterceptor
{
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FlexInterceptor.class);

public void afterCompletion(MessageProcessingContext context, Message inputMessage, Message outputMessage, Exception ex)
{
    logger.info(inputMessage.getMessageId());
}

public Message postProcess(MessageProcessingContext context, Message inputMessage, Message outputMessage)
{
    return outputMessage;
}

public Message preProcess(MessageProcessingContext context, Message inputMessage) {
    return inputMessage;
}
```

}

Comment: sorry what is message interceptor? never have heard of it

Answer (score 0):

In AMFEndpoint class [], there are fields

```
    /**
     * Returns the deserializer class name used by the endpoint.
     *
     * @return The deserializer class name used by the endpoint.
     */
    @Override protected String getDeserializerClassName()
    {
        return "flex.messaging.io.amf.AmfMessageDeserializer";
    }

    /**
     * Returns the serializer class name used by the endpoint.
     *
     * @return The serializer class name used by the endpoint.
     */
    @Override protected String getSerializerClassName()
    {
        return "flex.messaging.io.amf.AmfMessageSerializer";
    }
```

So I think you can extend the AMFendpoint and specify your own serializer/deserealizer and implement them, obviously. AmfMessageDeserializer source code is here:
http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/blazeds/branches/4.6_Apache/modules/core/src/flex/messaging/io/amf/AmfMessageDeserializer.java

Also I think if you want to change the messages sent from BlazeDS to Flex, you need to user Serializer rather than Deserializer.

Btw, downloading the whole source code for BlazeDS is pretty useful, you can add it to Eclipse and ctrl-click on classes and see the source with comments.